# elasticsearch 6.1 error : IOException while reading synonyms_path_path

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 6.1 and I am trying to add a basic synonym filter to my settings following this doc : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html

Here is my code :

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test_index?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"settings": {
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "search_synonyms" : {
                  "type": "custom",
                  "tokenizer" : "keyword",
                  "filter" : ["lowercase","synonyms"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "synonyms" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonyms.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}'
```

And I get the following error message :

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "IOException while reading synonyms_path_path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/analysis/synonyms.txt"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "IOException while reading synonyms_path_path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/analysis/synonyms.txt",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "no_such_file_exception",
      "reason" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/analysis/synonyms.txt"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I believe the issue comes from the "... reading synonyms_path_path:" which should probably be just "... reading synonyms_path:".

However, I believe I respected all features as mentioned in the doc.

Moreover, if I try just to put :

```
"filter" : {
     "synonyms" : {
          "type" : "synonym",
          "synonyms" : "analysis/synonyms.txt"
      }
 }
```

It just does not read the file then...

My synonyms.txt is the exact same file as shown in the doc for solr format.

Any thoughts or suggestion on how to fix this?

Thank you very much in advance for you time.

Comment: Create a file in the mentioned location(/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/analysis/synonyms.txt) & try to run again.

Comment: The file synonyms.txt is present and readable in the mentioned location. The error does not come from there. But thank you for your help :).

Comment: After some more research, it seems that the issue comes from the fact that I use a docker to run ES 6.1. And I don't know how it works to either put the synonyms.txt file in the right place or to map the volume properly so the docker can access the file.

Answer (score 0):

By using the following command on file, I fixed the error message :

```
sudo chmod 777 synonyms.txt
```

But the analyzer still does not recognize the synonyms present in the file.
Indeed synonyms.txt contains : i-pod, i pod => ipod

And if I try :

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test_index/_analyze?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "analyzer": "search_synonyms",
  "text": "i pod"
}'
```

I get :

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "i pod",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Problem not yet entirely solved, but getting there :).

Comment: Sorry for this answer, a typo in my analyzer definition mislead me. It should be :
"search_synonyms" : {
  "type" : "custom",
  "tokenizer": "keyword",
  "filter" : ["lowercase", "synonyms"]
}

But when I correct it, I get back to the same error as mentioned in my first post...

Answer (score 0):

```
"filter" : {
     "synonyms" : {
          "type" : "synonym",
          "synonyms" : "synonyms.txt"
      }
 }
```

Try this. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Little late, but I had the same issue with docker, as Aurelien Quillet pointed out.

You probably need something like

```yaml
services:
    elasticsearch_container:
        volumes:
            - ${APPLICATION}/config/packages/synonyms.txt:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/synonyms.txt
```

In my case `${APPLICATION}/config/packages/synonyms.txt` is the path in my project code.

The path shown in the error (`/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/synonyms.txt`) is the path in my **elasticsearch** container.